# How are both of these referring to the same variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a very confusing situation...

```
(function sayStuff(){
    this.word = "hello2";
    (function (){
        console.log(this.word);
    }())
}())


var myObject = {
    word: "bar",
    func: function() {
        (function() {
            console.log(this.word);
        }());
    }
};
myObject.func();
```

Outputs

hello2
hello2

How is this happening? How can the closure on the 'func' of myObject actually see the variable that is referenced in sayStuff()? I thought IIFE were meant to protect internals from Global scope?

Comment: I tried but told me I had to wait 8 minutes, and I didn't log in since learning. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both cases, `this` is `window`, the global default context replacing the one you don't provide when you call the internal function expressions.

If you want to keep the context, don't use IIFE internally or call them with the context :

```
(function sayStuff(){
    this.word = "hello2"; // still this is window, use var if you don't want that
        (function() {
            console.log(this.word); // window.word
        }).call(this); // well, this is window...
}())


var myObject = {
    word: "bar",
    func: function() {
        (function() {
            console.log(this.word); // myObject.word
        }).call(this);
    }
};
myObject.func();
```

Answer (score 2):

IIFE only hide locally scoped variables (i.e. those created with the `var` keyword).

All your functions that touch `this.word` are invoked in the global context (i.e. not as methods of an object, not with the `new` keyword and not with `apply`, `call` or `bind`), so `this` is `window` in each case. You are dealing with global variables.

If you wanted a private variable you would do something more like this:

```
(function (){
    var word = "hello2";
    (function (){
        console.log(word);
    }())
}())
```